# Use a class static variable as part of a closure use list

Tags: php

I would like to "use" a static class variable as part as the *use* list statement of a closure ?

Following snippets simply fail as ***unexpected 'self'*** parse errors.

`array_walk($_categories, function($c, $i) use (&self::$tree) {`
OR
`array_walk($_categories, function($c, $i) use (self::&$tree) {`

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'self' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Is there any special syntax to use in this very special case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why on earth would you want to do that? Given your use of `self`, the closure is clearly defined within the class somewhere, so you're able to access the static member anyway:

```
class Foo
{
    protected static $bar = 123;

    public function test()
    {
        return function($x) {
            static::$bar += $x; // or self::$bar
            return static::$bar;
        };
    }
}

$x = new Foo;
$y = $x->test();

var_dump($y(1));//int(124)
var_dump($y(2));//int(126)
```

No need to muck about with references at all...

If you're on an EOL'ed version of PHP (5.3 for example), you could work around the problem by assigning a reference to the static member first, and then pass a reference to that reference via `use`:

```
public function test()
{
    $staticRef = &static::$bar;
    return function($x) use (&$staticRef) {
        $staticRef += $x;
        return $staticRef;
    };
}
```

But if you're still working with a version of PHP that was EOL'ed long ago, really you should be upgrading...

Comment: I simply thought lambdas did not have access to the class wide context. But actually it does. I got ride of the _**use**_ list and now simply use the `self::$tree` right from inside the closure _(using 5.5.9)_. Thank you.